# Cannot save script file in qgis

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am using the qgis python editor to create a script and run it. When I am done writing my script, I would like to save it. However when I click on `Save as` I get the following error

An error has occurred while executing Python code:

```
AttributeError: 'QDir' object has no attribute 'replace' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\console\console.py", line 660, in saveAsScriptFile
    pathFileName = os.path.join(folder, fileName)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 65, in join
    result_drive, result_path = splitdrive(path)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 116, in splitdrive
    normp = p.replace(altsep, sep)
AttributeError: 'QDir' object has no attribute 'replace'


Python version: 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:25:58) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 2.18.22 Las Palmas, 5a99678469 

Python Path:
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python
C:/Users/aboufira/.qgis2/python
C:/Users/aboufira/.qgis2/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin\python27.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg
C:/Users/aboufira/.qgis2//python
C:\Users\aboufira\.qgis2\python\plugins\DigitizingTools\tools
C:/Users/aboufira/.qgis2/python/plugins\pdokservicesplugin
```

I have no idea how to resolve this, has anyone seen this before?

Comment: you might want to report this as a bug; it looks very like [this closed issue](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/17106)